# iPhone: ASCII art works fine when assigned explicitly to a label but does not work for Sqlite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, ascii-art

I am making an iPhone app which has ASCII art.

I face a problem when I store the ASCII art in Sqlite or plist and retrieve it into a label.

```
smslbl.text = @"___________\n |---------|-O\n/___________\\\n|______________|\n\\____________/";
```

When I explicitly give the string as above. The ASCII appears properly on view.

But when I retrieve the same text from database and assign it to the same label then it prints all the text in the same line. What should I do?

Comment: have you run a check to see if what comes out of sqlite is the same as what you put in? i.e., no extra backslashes or any other quoting or escaping?

Comment: Yes, it comes out the same. but it is shown in a single line in label along with backslash and newline characters as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the compiler or the runtime is translating the "\n" sequences for you in the constant NSString you have there. This behavior can *only* be seen in constant strings like your example. If you have that exact string inside of a database and you pull it out, it will not be parsed for escapes. In order to get that behavior, you need to parse the string yourself. But in this case, why have escapes at all in the database? There's no reason not to just put the unescaped version in your database, complete with actual newline characters.

Comment: I am a newbie.So can you please guide me on how to parse the string when we fetch it from the database? Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to store the string with backslash-escapes like this in your database? It's almost certainly not what you want to do. If you feel you must, you can parse the string with NSScanner or with string searching. In either case, search for a backslash, read the next character, and interpret it as desired (treat \n as a newline, and anything else as the literal character after the backslash).

Comment: ok thanx. If storing the string with backslash-escapes doesnot help much then I am not sure that I will store it into my database. Also can you give some example for parsing. As I have a blur idea but the parsing is still not very clear to me. Thanks for answering :)